# Find the number of positive integers that are divisors of at least one of $10^{10}, 12^{12}$ or $15^{15}$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Find the number of positive integers that are divisors of at least one of $10^{10}, 12^{12}, 15^{15}$.
As far as I have reached is the number of factors are 121,325,256 respectively

Comment: Just consider the prime factorization of the three numbers.

Comment: So now eliminate duplicates

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the *inclusion-exclusion formula*.  It shouldn't be very long, as each pair of numbers has only one common prime factor.